# Same click function from multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Not sure if the tilte is correct for this issue, but here goes.

I am publishing links in a for loop like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){ 
    echo '<tr class="game-green">
             <td>
                 Playing against <strong>'.$oppname.'</strong><br />Game ID: <strong>'.$oppid.'></strong>
                 <a id="test" class="btn btn-primary btn-single btn-sm" style="float:right;" data-id="'.$oppid.'^'.$playerid.'" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Edit</a>
             </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

As you can see each a href has the id=test due to my jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var data = $(this).data("id").split('^');
        $('#myModal').modal({
            remote: 'assets/modals/gameinfo.php?gameid='+data[0]+'&playerid='+data[1],
            show: true
        });
    }); 
});
```

But when clicking any link besides the first nothing happens. I guess its because they all have the same id... But I can't figure out how to get past this.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: why are you giving them all the same id. instead you should use class. i.e.: class="test ..." then $(".test").click(...);

Comment: But wouldn't that give the same?

Comment: no it wouldn't be the same. id is meant to be unique, but you can have multiple elements with the same class

Comment: Never give two elements the same ID. That's what classes are for. Only 1 unique ID per page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a class selectior, like so

```
$('.test').click(function(){
...
```

and instead of having the same id for each achor tag, which is invalid format and very wrong thing to do especially when id is meant to be unique value in the dom.. have the same class name and assign the click listener to each of the a tags.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `id`, try using a different attribute, `data-id` for instance. This would make it a valid selector and you could apply the click function to all elements.

```
<a data-id="test"....</a>
```

Then select it with:

```
$('a[data-id="test"]').click(...
```